# Correct way to write file location

Tags: c++, include

What is the correct way to include files

```
#include "../myDirecoty/myFile.h"
```

or

```
#include  "..\myDirecoty\myFile.h"
```

the difference is the direction of "/" or "\".

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @reggie: That document doesn't event mention the slashes, does it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
#include "../myDirecoty/myFile.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, but the first form is more "clear" because sometime people thinks to \ as an escaping character in string (but include path are not strings)

Comment: There is a difference: the backslash being a path separator on Windows is a perfectly legal character in a UNIX filename (Mac OS X is also a UNIX, BTW). So the later will create a file-not-found error on all systems, except Windows and DOS.

Comment: @DarkDust: You are right... I'm too used to work on Windows and most of time I forgot unix :-(

Answer (score 0):

normal slashes "/", best compatible

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen looking through the code on my computer, you should use forward slashes ('/').

Answer (score 0):

The backslash `\` is used on Windows and DOS, while the slash `/` is used on all UNIX/POSIX compatible systems (like Linux and Mac OS X). So the later can produce a file-not-found error on non-Windows systems. AFAIK all Windows compiler do support the slash `/`, so this is one to use.

**Edit:** See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573430/c-include-header-path-change-windows-to-linux).